# GetStaticProps Revalidate is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, next.js, i18next, supabase

**Problem:**
Revalidate doesn't work when im useing (**serverSideTranslations**) from next-i18next. Please see my code below.

When a new user register, an static page is generated for each language: ***(da (Default), en, sv, de).***
Everyting works fine with the code below, for allready generated pages at build time (When deployed on Vercel).

When a new user register, the page wont get revalidated and thorws a 500 Internal server error. / The page was not generated

Please see comment in code!

```js
export async function getStaticPaths({ locales }) {
  const { data: profiles, error } = await supabase.from("profiles").select("*");
  console.log(locales);

  const paths = profiles
    .map((profile) =>
      locales.map((locale) => ({
        params: { profileName: profile.username },
        locale, // Pass locale here
      }))
    )
    .flat();

  console.log(paths);
  return { paths, fallback: "blocking" };
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params, locale }) {
  const { data: profiles, error } = await supabase
    .from("profiles")
    .select("*")
    .eq("username", params.profileName)
    .single();

  return {
    props: {
      profiles,
      ...(await serverSideTranslations(locale, ["Profil"])), //When this line is removed everything works fine  --- When its added GetStaticPaths and GetStaticProps breaks.
    },
    revalidate: 30,
  };
}
```

Comment: _"When a new user register, the page wont get revalidated and thorws a 500 Internal server error"_ - Do you see any error message/stack on the server when that happens?

Comment: No it works perfect in localhost, but not on the deployed version on vercel.

Im not sure how to recreate the error in localhost, as the page will be generated when i visit the url.

Comment: Check for error messages in Vercel [Function logs](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/deployments/logs#function-logs).

Comment: I get no error in vercel

Comment: If the page throws a 500 error, there should definitely be an error message about that in Vercel logs.